# Android app installs and runs from Eclipse but will not run when installed from .apk file on phone

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, android-windowmanager, android-task

I have an app I've been developing for Android. The application installs and runs fine from Eclipse but when I export the `.apk`, put it on the phone and install it then the app will not run and closes.

I get this message in logcat:

```
05-01 14:57:21.167: E/WindowState(839): getStack: Window{1655a746 u0 com.example.testapp/com.example.testapp.MainActivity} 
couldn't find taskId=551 Callers=com.android.server.wm.WindowState.computeFrameLw:1054     
com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager.layoutWindowLw:4904 
com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutLockedInner:10917 
com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.performLayoutAndPlaceSurfacesLockedInner:11857
```

Has anyone else come across this before? any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Actually this what is causing the problem:

```
 05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): Process: com.example.testapp, PID: 17907 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/testapp/MainActivity$2; 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at com.example.testapp.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:3503) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1650) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2536)   
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2760) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5944) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1389)
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1184) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
    "com.example.testapp.MainActivity$2" on path:
     DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sentinor.gmcobweb_c2im-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]] 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56) 05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): ... 15 more 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sentinor.gmcobweb_c2im.MainActivity$2 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504) 
    05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): ... 16 more 05-01 15:13:32.355: E/AndroidRuntime(17907): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: what do you mean "runs fine from Eclipse", you mean on an emulator? Also please provide the full stack trace

Comment: I mean I can install the app to my phone from eclipse and it runs fine but when I install it from .apk file on my phone it will crash everytime I try to open it

Comment: Is MainActivity defined in you Manifest? What the minSdkVersion in your manifest and is your phone at or above that?

Comment: Are you using proguard?

Comment: The distinction here is not between eclipse and an on-device install, it is between a debug apk and a release one which has gone through a misconfigured proguard stage that removed an anonymous innner class whose necessity was not obvious to the tool.  You will have to explicitly list it as required.  See the many proguard questions here.